# Import database: SQL Server 2005 Express to SQL Server 2008 Enterprise

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, database, sql

I have two servers

1 x SQL Server 2005 Express and
1 x SQL Server 2008 Enterprise

How can I move/import my database from SQL Server 2005 Express to SQL Server 2008 Enterprise?

(BACKUP SQL SERVER 2005 and RESTORE to SQL Server 2008, would that work?)

Comment: (BACKUP SQL SERVER 2005 and RESTORE to SQL Server 2008, would that work?)

Did you try?

Comment: As this question is not programming related, it will probably be closed and migrated to ServerFault.com, which is the proper forum for System Administration questions such as this.

Comment: I disagree that this isn't programming related, I've had this issue on the Oracle side and I'm no DBA or SysAdmin...

Answer (score 1):

yes you can backup db from sql server 2005 and restore it to sql server 2008. also you can import db from sql server 2005 in sql server 2008. for this create a new db on sql server 2008, then press right click of mouse on the name of created db. after that from task menu press Import Data... . in this step you can specify your source and destination dbs.

Answer (score 0):

I must be doing something wrong? i tried to restore a SQL Server 2005 to a SQL Server 2008 and received the following error:

===================================

Restore failed for Server 'DATABASE1'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

---

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.0.1600.22+((SQL_PreRelease).080709-1414+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Restore+Server&LinkId=20476

---

Program Location:

at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore.SqlRestore(Server srv)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.RestoreFilegroupsPropertiesTask.ApplyChanges(RunType runType, ExecutionMode& executionResult)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.RestoreFilegroupsProperties.DoPreProcessExecution(RunType runType, ExecutionMode& executionResult)

===================================

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

---

Program Location:

at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection sqlCommands, ExecutionTypes executionType)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection queries)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.BackupRestoreBase.ExecuteSql(Server server, StringCollection queries)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore.SqlRestore(Server srv)

===================================

The media set has 2 media families but only 1 are provided. All members must be provided.
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

---

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.00.1600&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=3132&LinkId=20476

---

Server Name: DATABASE1
Error Number: 3132
Severity: 16
State: 1
Line Number: 1

---

Program Location:

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)